# General equation of perpendicular direction vectors

Tags: vectors

Say we have a vector $$\vec{A} = a\hat{i} + b\hat{j} + c\hat{k} $$
So how do we find the general equation to all the perpendicular unit vectors, say, $\hat{b}$?

I know a “cheap” method to this problem by considering any random vector that’s not parallel to $\vec{A}$ and taking a cross product with it to find a single perpendicular vector to $\vec{A}$ but I want to find all the unit vectors in one general equation.

Comment: did you mean ijk instead of iii? Extend $\vec A$ to an orthogonal basis $\vec A , \vec B , \vec C$ then the set of all perpendicular vectors is the linear span of $\vec B$ and $\vec C$. Normalise and you get unit ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, let's define a vector space with vectors perpendicular to $\vec A$. We can pick a trivial perpendicular vector for our basis, like $[b,-a,0]$. For future convenience, we want our basis to have perpendicular vectors, so we'll cross product our first two vectors to get a third, perpendicular to both of them, $[-ac,bc,a^2+b^2]$. Let's name our two new vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ respectively. We can create a formula for all the perpendicular unit vectors to $\vec A$ by scaling $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ down to lengths of 1, and using the formula for a circle from perpendicular vectors: $$\frac{\vec x}{||\vec x||}cos\theta+\frac{\vec y}{||\vec y||}sin\theta$$ Substituting for $a$, $b$, and $c$ creates: $$\frac{bi-aj}{a^2+b^2}cos\theta+\frac{-aci+bcj+a^2k+b^2k}{a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^4+b^4+2a^2b^2}sin\theta$$which, simplified, becomes:$$[\frac{bcos\theta}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{acsin\theta}{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)},\frac{bcsin\theta}{(a^2+b^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}-\frac{acos\theta}{a^2+b^2},\frac{sin\theta}{a^2+b^2+c^2}]$$

Comment: pedantic point: you are not guaranteed that $[b,-a,0]\neq 0$